# How to increment a JavaScript variable name

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Searches turned up some similar questions, all with the best answer suggesting that the OP use an array, but in my case I can't (or I am not knowledgeable enough yet).

I have this snippet of code from a page using the Google Maps API v3.

```
// var locations is defined outside this snippet. it's an array of location data (long/lat, name, etc)
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map,
      icon: iconImage
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

I need to be able to trigger that `google.maps.event.addListener` through a click outside of the Google Maps code. My problem is that the variable `marker` is not unique and I am not even 100% sure how this snippet works (how does `marker` not get overridden and lost every time?).

How can I trigger the click of a particular `marker`?

Comment: Most people use an array of markers.  Should be lots of duplicates of this.

Comment: Why can´t you use an array? `var marker, i, markers = [];` and within the for loop you write `markers.push(marker)`. Btw, `marker` does get overridden everytime, but the event is actually bound to the DOM object and not the variable.

Answer (score 0):

As the question is being edited:

To trigger the click on a particular marker you can use:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click');
```

Ir order to do that you need to store your markers somewhere like an array when you create them.

Comment: I don't think the array is needed at all after you've taken care of the multiple `marker`s (and `i`s) in those closures.